# Maximum call stack size exceeded in javascript canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

so i am making a grid game in canvas where if one square is selected, the squares of the same color around it are also selected and when the square is clicked, the selected squares burst and new squares fall down.

the grid i have made is of 9 rows and 15 columns -

```
tile_array = [[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]];
```

and i am filling in the grid with random color tiles.
and heres my on hover function -

```
function over_tile(our_tile) {//, pointer
    our_tile.alpha = 0.5;
    if (our_tile.tile_row > 0) { // top row availiable
        top_tile = this.tile_array[our_tile.tile_row-1][our_tile.tile_column];
        if (top_tile.tile_color == our_tile.tile_color) {
            this.over_tile(top_tile);
        };
    };
    if (our_tile.tile_column < 14) { // right column availiable
        right_tile = this.tile_array[our_tile.tile_row][our_tile.tile_column+1];
        if (right_tile.tile_color == our_tile.tile_color) {
            this.over_tile(right_tile);
        };
    };
    if (our_tile.tile_column > 0) { // left column availiable
        left_tile = this.tile_array[our_tile.tile_row][our_tile.tile_column-1];
        if (left_tile.tile_color == our_tile.tile_color) {
            this.over_tile(left_tile);
        };
    };
    if (our_tile.tile_row < 8) { // bottom row availiable
        bottom_tile = this.tile_array[our_tile.tile_row+1][our_tile.tile_column];
        if (bottom_tile.tile_color == our_tile.tile_color) {
            this.over_tile(bottom_tile);
        };
    };
}
```

now the problem i am facing is that the above is creating a call stack size exceeded error.
but in the function if i comment out parts and try some variations are working -

1. left column, bottom row
2. left column, top row
3. right column, bottom row
4. right column, top row

and these are creating errors -

1. left column, right column
2. top row, bottom row

and any three or all combinations are not working together and each of them is working alone. i can't seem to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the matrix be such :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

When you do bottom+left on, for example, 5, the calls are expanding so:

```
5->4->7->fin

5->8->7->fin
```

Similarly in other working cases.

In the case of bottom+top, on 5, you will get:

```
5->2->5 (lower than 2)->2 (higher than 5)->5->2->...
```

Similarly in other cases which do not work.

Try to mark visited tiles so you will never visit them again.

Comment: i just put in an alpha check and it worked. thanks again